# In list of tables,longtable caption repeats equal to the number of pages occupied by a long table

Tags: longtable

In list of tables,longtable caption repeats equal to the number of pages occupied by a long table. i only want to show the caption and pagne number once for a whole long table. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `\caption` is inside the table head?

Then put it into `\endfirsthead` and use an empty optional argument for the `\caption` in the header of the following pages (`\endhead`).
An empty optional argument `\caption[]` suppresses the entry in the table of contents.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{l}
  \caption{Workers}
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Workers}
\endhead
  1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\
  11\\12\\13\\14\\15\\16\\17\\18\\19\\20\\
  21\\22\\23\\24\\25\\26\\27\\28\\29\\30\\
  31\\32\\33\\34\\35\\36\\37\\38\\39\\40\\
  41\\42\\43\\44\\45\\46\\47\\48\\49\\50\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The table spans three pages, but the table of contents only lists one entry:

> [image: \listoftables]

Also a table header can be given and repeated on each page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{l}
  \caption{Workers}\\
  Head\\
  \hline
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Workers}\\
  Head\\
  \hline
\endhead
  1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\
  11\\12\\13\\14\\15\\16\\17\\18\\19\\20\\
  21\\22\\23\\24\\25\\26\\27\\28\\29\\30\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]  [image: Page 3]

Comment: i noticed a problem, I am repeating the first row of my table on each row as well as the caption. when using this command, it removes the first row of the table on first page.

Comment: @Ahmad: Also a table header can be given along with the caption, if I understood your problem correctly, see updated answer.